# Delete next row if value of a variable is less than previous row + X in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I have a dataframe, with several variables. I need to select certain rows based on the "Time" variable (expressed in seconds). That is to say, I need to remove the rows comprised within the same 30 minutes time interval, and to keep only the first row of such intervals. In order to do this, I want to delete the next row if the value of the Time vector is equal to or less than the previous row's value + 1800 (30min *60sec). I need to apply this recursively to the dataframe, I imagine with a for loop.

Df sample:

```
>  Time   Open   High    Low  Close Volume     Wap Gap Count
1 1536154200 234.61 234.95 234.57 234.76    302 234.600   0    31
2 1536154260 234.76 235.23 234.76 235.16    135 235.008   0    94
3 1536154320 235.09 235.33 234.88 235.33    121 235.010   0   109
4 1536154380 235.24 235.35 235.08 235.35     24 235.203   0    22
5 1536154440 235.27 235.47 235.22 235.42     62 235.340   0    35
6 1536154500 235.39 235.81 235.39 235.63    136 235.633   0   110
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data?

Comment: In your sample the intervals between rows are all 60 seconds, thus only the first row would remain

Comment: I said I need to keep only first row of each 30 minutes interval, not 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter( (Time > (lag(Time)+1800))| row_number() == 1 )
```

Comment: You loose the first row, because `filter()` discards rows for which the logical vector is `NA`